# Sorting order music player android

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-music-player

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null,  MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
```

I want to sort audio by title name but running the above code ,i get capital letter audio first and then all the small letter audio.

how do i get absolute sort order,not mixed ordered list?

like from A to z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null,  MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
```

See if this works. I have not tried it, Just read somewhere long time back.